# Microsoft Excel not graphing, $x = y^{1/2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, math-software, data-analysis

Im not sure if this is a math question or a su question.

The experiment was relating the period of one "bounce" when you hang a weight on a spring and let it bounce.

I have this data here, one being mass and one being time.

The time is an average of 5 trials, each one being and average of 20 bounces, to minimize human error.

```
t 

0.3049s
0.3982s
0.4838s
0.5572s
0.6219s
0.6804s
0.7362s
0.7811s
0.8328s
0.869s
```

The mass is the mass that was used in each trial (they aren't going up in exact differences because each weight has a slight difference, nothing is perfect in the real world)

```
m

50.59g
100.43g
150.25g
200.19g
250.89g
301.16g
351.28g
400.79g
450.43g
499.71g
```

My problem is that I need to find the relationship between them, I know $m = \frac{k}{4\Pi^2}\times T^2$ so I can work out k like that but we need to graph it.

I can assume that the relationship is a sqrt relation, not sure on that one. But it appears to be the reverse of a square. Should it be $\frac{1}{x^2}$ then?

Either way my problem is still present, I have tried $\frac{1}{x}$, $\frac{1}{x^2}$, $\sqrt{x}$, $x^2$, none of them produce a straight line.

The problem for SU is that when I go to graph the data on Excel I set the y axis data (which is the weights) and then when I go to set the x axis (which is the time) it just replaces the y axis with what I want to be the x axis, this is only happening when I have the sqrt of "m" as the y axis and I try to set the x axis as the time.

The problem of math is that, am I even using the right thing? To get a straight line it would need to be $x = y^{1/2}$ right? I thought I was doing the right thing, it is what we were told to do. I'm just not getting anything that looks right.

Comment: If you want to produce something that kind of looks like a straight line, the conventional thing to do is to say put $m$ on the $x$-axis, and $T^2$ on the $y$-axis. Or else $\sqrt{m}$ on the $x$-axis, and $T$ on the $y$-axis. Or else reverse roles of $x$ and $y$. Whatever you do, you will not get a straight line, but there will be a line of best fit, obtainable through an Excel command that I have forgotten.

Comment: So the relationship is still a sqrt/sqr relationship right?

I just realised what I was thinking, I think I just need to identify the relationship, not produce a straight line.

Comment: We have for your data $T^2\approx c m$ for some constant $c$. Or equivalently $T\approx a \sqrt{m}$, or equivalently $m \approx b T^2$. It is for your data only a rough approximation.  Hooke's Law is only a rough model to begin with. The fit seems to be worst at the light end.

Comment: I've changed [tag:algebra] tag to [tag:algebra-precalculus], since we don't use algebra tag anymore, see [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/473/the-use-of-the-algebra-tag/3081#3081) for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the proper dependence using dimensional analysis.  The units of $k$, the spring constant, are force/displacement.  In the metric system, this is dyne/cm=g/s^2.  The units of mass are g, and period are s.  To get the units right, $T \propto \sqrt {\frac mk}$ and you are looking for the constant.  If you divide T by $\sqrt m$, your values cluster around $.39$  The 50g data is out of family, and being on the end, I would just exclude it.  Then the average is $T \approx 0.039724\sqrt m$